# FragmentDialog with fixed aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to implement `FragmentDialog` with fixed aspect ratio.It should be as tall as screen height(minus some padding) and width should be `dialogWidth=dialogHeight*ar`.Since `FragmentDialog` doesn't provide onMeasure method.I override this method in the dialog's content class:

```
public class PuzzleSelectorView extends FrameLayout {
public PuzzleSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    //Log.d("selector",heightSize+"");
    int dy=((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.selector_start_btn)).getHeight();
    int desiredWidth=(int) ((heightSize-dy) *ImagesItemView.IMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO);
    widthMeasureSpec=MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredWidth,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(desiredWidth, heightSize);
    //this.setMeasuredDimension(320,240);
}
}
```

Fragment class:

```
public class PuzzleSelectorFragment extends DialogFragment {
private Decryptor loader;
public void show(FragmentManager manager,String tag, String imgId) {
    super.show(manager,tag);
    //some unrelated code
}
@Override
public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Log.d("dialog","closed");
}
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_selector,null);
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

}
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
}
}
```

Content layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.rhyboo.net.listtest.layouts.PuzzleSelectorView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/selector_img_container"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/selector_start_btn"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

<com.rhyboo.net.listtest.layouts.CustomTextView
    app:customFont="Lato-Regular.ttf"
    android:text="@string/start_puzzle_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/background" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/selector_preloader"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

To show it I do:

```
PuzzleSelectorFragment selector=new PuzzleSelectorFragment();                    
selector.show(MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(),"selector",id);
```

It works fine on the real device(Android 5.1.1):
[image: real device]

But when I run on the emulator(Android 7.1) I got corrupted layout:
[image]

My question is: am I moving in the right direction by setting fragment's size inside content class onMeasure?If not where should I set it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason if I set content's view size with `setMeasuredDimension`, `FragmentDialog` in android 7 doesn't layout correctly `ImageViews` with `BitmapDrawable` inside it.Solved by overriding onLayout and calling childs' `layout` method with desired dimensions.